# How to set the ZoneOffset for Berlin time zone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset, java-time

I am getting the `LocalDateTime` two hours lesser than the real time. How can I get the offset time for Berlin, Germany for the code below?

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a `ZoneId` and a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");

long seconds = 1_556_000_000;

ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds).atZone(zone);
String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter);
System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

The output from this snippet is:

> 23.04.2019 08:13:20

My example seconds value corresponds to 06:13:20 UTC, so you’ve got your two hours offset from UTC respected.

Summer time (DST) is built in, so in winter you will get only 1 hour from UTC as you should. Historic changes in the offset work out of the box too, and known future changes (what happens in Germany after 2021 no one knows).